# flux:form.section inside another flux:form.section not rendering flux:form.object Properly

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am creating a Layerslider with Fluid Content Element (FCE).

Below Is my code.

```
<flux:form.sheet name="elements" label="Elements">


    <flux:form.section name="slides" label="Slides">

        <flux:form.object name="slide" label="Slide">

            <flux:field.input name="title" label="Slide Title" />
            <flux:field.text name="layersliderdata" enableRichText="0" rows="4" label="Layerslider data" />
            <flux:field.file name="background" allowed="jpg,png,jpeg,gif" label="Background" />
            <flux:field.file name="thumbnail" allowed="jpg,png,jpeg,gif" label="Thumbnail" />

            <flux:form.section name="elements" label="Elements">
                <flux:form.object name="text" label="Text">
                    <flux:field.text name="content" rows="3" label="Text" />
                    <flux:field.select name="type" items="p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8" label="Type" />
                    <f:render section="SharedObjectFields" arguments="{_all}" />
                </flux:form.object>
                <flux:form.object name="image" label="Image">
                    <flux:field.file name="file" allowed="jpg,png,jpeg,gif" label="Image file" />
                    <f:render section="SharedObjectFields" arguments="{_all}" />
                </flux:form.object>
            </flux:form.section>

        </flux:form.object>

    </flux:form.section>

</flux:form.sheet>

<f:section name="SharedObjectFields">

    <flux:field.text name="style" enableRichText="0" rows="4" label="CSS Styles" />
    <flux:field.text name="layersliderdata" enableRichText="0" rows="4" label="Layerslider data" />
    <flux:field.input name="class" label="Class" />

</f:section>
```

I am Getting Result Like this.

[image]

[image]

But I want Result as per below screenshot.

[image]
[image]

I Dont Know. What's going wrong.
I am using below Versions of fluid elements.

Typo3 6.2.14

vhs 2.3.3

fluidcontent 4.2.4

fluidpages 3.2.3

flux 7.2.1

I can confirm this on **dcngmbh/moox_core** for **Split Button with DropDown** FCE (Fluid Content Element) in which its display result in backend like this.

http://screencast.com/t/wIeYk8AUmGl

http://screencast.com/t/QLqnSmpy

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue some days ago using fluidcontent. It seems, there is a bug in flux, which has been [fixed](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/827) in the GitHub repositories. You could try to switch to the development version of flux or wait for an official release on TER.